# Call to undefined method File::save()

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have checked all thread with same issue but still can't find out why isn't working. I have this function

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\MediaKit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Validator ;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class MediaKitController extends Controller
{
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
      $this->validate($request, [

            'filename' => 'required',
            'filename.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip,png'
      ]);

    if($request->hasfile('filename'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('filename') as $files)
        {
            $name = $files->getClientOriginalName();
            $files->move(public_path().'/files/', $name);  
            $data[] = $name;  
        }
    }

    $files= new \File();
    $files->filename=json_encode($data);       
    $files->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'Your files has been successfully added');
}
```

When I try to save the file(s) to the database I've got the following error. The files are saved in the directory.

> "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::save()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;` to your model namespace.
2. Replace this `$files= new \File();` to `$files= new File();`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but where to replace #1?

Comment: Thank's this fixed the issue. One addition question - Do you have idea why the uploaded file has `[]` around the name?

Comment: @Ivanov maybe it is the result of `json_encode()`. Do you decode it when getting from db? And I recomment you to use `protected $casts = ['filename' => 'array'];` to model (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators). Eloquent can auto json_encode/json_decode arrays.

Comment: Thanks @IndianCoding!